# Reusing a Complex type in a table or multiple tables with different nullability?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to map a Complex Type to multiple columns in a table or in multiple tables with different nullability.

Let's say I have entities something like:

```
public class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public Phone CellPhone { get; set; }
    public Phone HomePhone { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    public Phone PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Phone FaxNumber { get; set;}
}
```

and the configuration is something like:

```
public class ContactConfiguration
{
    public ContactConfiguration()
    {
        Property(x => x.CellPhone.Number).HasColumnName("CellPhone").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.HomePhone.Number).HasColumnName("HomePhone").IsOptional();
    }
}

public class OrganizationConfiguration
{
    public OrganizationConfiguration()
    {
        Property(x => x.PhoneNumber.Number).HasColumnName("Phone").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.FaxNumber.Number).HasColumnName("Fax").IsOptional();
    }
}
```

Mapping the Phone to different columns for different names works fine, but setting the nullability doesn't. EF complains that the IsNull is not consistent.

I know that I can make it work if I introduce a Fax inheriting Phone but this would only work for one table. If I had another column for Phone type, I would have to create another type from Phone. I don't think this is feasible.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue to track this on our CodePlex site - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1247

This is a limitation of EF in general (rather than just Code First) and is a side effect of the format we use to represent the model. Unfortunately that makes it difficult to change, so we won't be able to change it in the EF6 release. We'll have to consider the effort required and the priority of the change for future releases.

The best workaround would be to have two complex types RequiredPhone and OptionalPhone.